# Be informed when a specific vdso is run

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, system-calls

I'm currently trying to implement my own VDSO. I have used [this tutorial](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/creating-vdso-colonels-other-chicken) which explains how to do this for a 2.6 kernel.

I tested it and I got this working. (I succeeded in creating a kernel variable and accessing it from userland.)

Is there a way to be know in the kernel when the vdso has been called? I assume this can't be done synchronously (as the vdso is handled in userland). But is there any possibility (even dirty) from the kernel to know whether the function has been called (maybe with a hardware breakpoint or something)?

What I’d like to do is something like the function `my_vdso_has_been_called()`) in this code:

```
void update_vsyscall(/* […] */) {
    // […]
    if(my_vdso_has_been_called())
        do_something();
}
```

Note: the function `update_vsyscall` can be found in `arch/x86/kernel/vsyscall_64.c`

Comment: can something like `SystemTap` react to your `__vdso_myvdso` being called?

Comment: If I understand well, SystemTap is a tool only called from outside the kernel. So unless there is an equivalent tool running in kernelmode, I don’t think so. But correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: SystemTap compiles code into the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know how to declare a shared variable and access it from both the kernel and the vDSO, you can use that: declare a new variable, and increment it from the vDSO whenever it’s called.

Comment: In my understanding, theses shared variables are read-only from the userland.

Thus, this code will compile but if I uncomment the incremenation I’m having a segfault.

   `notrace int __vdso_myvdso(void) {`
    `// ++*vmyvar;  /* The program will crash if I uncomment this*/`
    ` return *vmyvar;`
    `}`

Am I doing it wrong? Are there other variables I can modify? Or can I disable this read-only protection?

Comment: Sorry, you’re right, `VVAR` only gives read-only access from the vDSO.

Comment: I’m trying to disable this read-only protection. Do you know how could I do that? I added the `VM_WRITE` flag to `install_special_mapping` in `arch_setup_additional_pages(…)`  from `vma.c` but this is not enough (I still get a segfault when I increment my variable). Do you know what the additional adaptations are?